# How to display the number of stacks in the stack column?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for my app, in my requirement I need to display the no.of stacks in column stack chart.

my code is

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        stackLabels: {
            style: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            enabled: true,
            y: 0,
             formatter: function () {             
                return this.total +"-"+this.touched;
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [129.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    },{
        data: [144.0, null, null]
    },{
        data: [800, null, 135.6]
    }]
});
```

In StackLabels im using "this.touched", But i need to display the count of visible stack

please look at the below example

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is correct or not. There might be another simpler way. But this works for your situation. Please check.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        stackLabels: {
            style: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            enabled: true,
            y: 0,
            formatter: function () {
              let count = 0;
              for (let i=0; i<this.axis.series.length; i++) {
                if (this.points[i] !== null) count++;
              }
              return count;
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [129.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    },{
        data: [144.0, null, null]
    },{
        data: [800, null, 135.6]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Basing on the `touched` property is not a good solution because it is doubled with each render.

Comment: In that case we can use series count. This will give count based on input data. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hLswunt/

Comment: You're right, then it's a better solution than iterating over the labels with `render()`